# Need to pass specific JQueryEventObject AND parameters to trigger

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-trigger

I am using custom events to broadcast navigation messages (between related plugins).

The simple trigger code currently looks like this:

```
$button.trigger('navigate', { url: link, target: target });
```

The receiving code looks like:

```
$element.on('navigate', function (e, params)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do something custom here with params.url and params.target
});
```

The problem is I also need to test `isDefaultPrevented()` on the event object that was sent to `trigger`.

I can create a custom event object and test it with:

```
 var eo = $.Event('navigate');
 $button.trigger(eo);
 if (!eo.isDefaultPrevented())
 {
      // Do the default actions
 }
```

But jQuery's `trigger()` does not have a version that takes both a `JQueryEventObject` *and* parameters and I can't figure out how to pass the parameters through with the trigger.

**Note:** I do not want to use the `e.data` property as loads of existing code expects the params object to be provided *as the second parameter* to any event handlers. I would prefer something that worked like this:

```
 var eo = $.Event('navigate');
 $button.trigger(eo, { url: link, target: target });
```

**Q: How do you use a custom `JQueryEventObject` *and* pass parameters to `trigger`?**

**Note:** I am using TypeScript, so I am going by what the jQuery definitions file says is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not documented, but [jQuery trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) actually does support what I was trying to do (pass an event object *and* parameters).

The relevant jQuery code looks like this (only one method, so the second parameter were just treated as optional and the first parameter can be a `string` *or* an `JQueryEventObject`):

```
trigger: function( type, data ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, this );
    });
```

My problem lay with trusting the documentation and the TypeScript definition file for Jquery (ie.. jQuery.d.ts) which only has these entries:

```
trigger(eventType: string, ...extraParameters: any[]): JQuery;
trigger(event: JQueryEventObject): JQuery;
```

behind the scenes however I found you can actually pass:

```
trigger(event: JQueryEventObject, extraParameters: any[]): JQuery;
```

**Option 1:**

The `TypeScript` solution is to either cast the element to *any* (which is bad) e.g.:

```
(<any>element).trigger(eo, {url: link, target: target});
```

or to add a new `TypeScript` definition for JQuery to allow for the extra parameters:

**Option 2: (best answer)**

```
// Declare our additions to JQuery object
interface JQuery
{
    trigger(event: JQueryEventObject, ...extraParameters: any[]): JQuery;
}
```

**I traced into Jquery using the first option, then went with the second option.**

Comment: Is that interface something you created for TypeScript? To give you the proper definitions?

Comment: @jwatts1980: Yes, you can create parallel interface definitions, anywhere in TypeScript files, and they will be merged for that object (ie. jQuery).